# include не прописывается через js

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5

Всем добрый вечер. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при коде `document.getElementById('message_box').innerHTML = "<?php include 'send.php'; ?>"` в консоли появляется ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` При этом, если прописать `<?php include 'send.php'; ?>` в голом HTML, то все функционирует нормально. С чем может быть связанна такая проблема ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно в `send.php` не экранированы кавычки в html-атрибутах. Попробуйте обернуть не в двойные кавычки, а в обратные (` `)

Comment: в выводе send.php в принципе могут оказаться акцентные символы `\`\``, и всё также сломается

Comment: @mymedia  при таком коде "по волосам не плачут"